# Syntax errors ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, apt, sh, syntax

every time i update my system using the sudo apt update command in the terminal i notice this at the bottom.

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected 
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected 
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected 
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected 
Reading package lists... Done
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: please [edit] your question with the **actual command** you are using in terminal

Comment: Nothing for us to go on. Best you will get is to fix your sources list: there is a syntax error in there. I would assume this is created by you by editing a file so try to remember what flle you changed recently ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have some faulty configuration at:

/etc/apt/sources.list

or some other file inside /etc/apt folder.

Comment: full error is this Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected                        
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Could be that in /etc/apt/sources.list you have mistake or if you have added it with: sudo add-apt-repository it will make /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-python3_10-jammy-jammy.list that should have content of: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/python3.10-jammy/ubuntu/ jammy main. Try sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes* and after that: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/python3.10-jammy.

Comment: Check also: 'sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list' and check if there is any refrence to *deadsnakes*.